# Sicilian dragon classic games

Tags: sicilian-dragon

I am trying to collect a list of Sicilian Dragon classic games, which every dragon player must be aware. I would really appreciate if you could share some classics and also highlight the most important move/part in the game.

I am okay with either color winning. The two games where the dragon kills the Yugoslav that immediately spring to mind are Kasparov's dragon vs Viswananthan Anand in 1995 WC

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1018626

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1018628

Answer (score 3):

[Fischer - Larsen, Portoroz 1958](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1008373) also known as "Slaying the Dragon" in his book, 60 Memorable games is <strike>recommended</strike> **required** reading.

The opening moves for the dragon, accelerated and hyperaccelerated dragon may be found in Parimarjan Negi's *e4 vs. the Sicilian: Vol 2*.

Answer (score 2):

[Karpov-Kortchnoi from the 1974](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1067858) Candidates Final which turned out to decide the World Champion is a famous and appealing dragon game and part of chess history.